# Error in PHP code, Line // Col Non-existent?

Tags: sphinx

WHen I try to run indexer for sphinx.

```
/usr/bin/indexer --rotate --all
```

I get this error...

```
using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
ERROR: invalid section type 'Strict' in /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf line 1617 col 8.
ERROR: invalid section type 'Strict' in /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf line 1617 col 1.
FATAL: failed to parse config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'
```

When I check sphinx.conf there is no line 1617. The last line of code is 1373. Could someone tell this newb what I'm doing wrong and how do I debug a line that doesn't exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Abd how it's connected with `php`?

Comment: Could you please paste an output of `ls -ln /etc/sphinx`?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a dynamic config file? ie contains embedded PHP code?

If so try running the config file on its own, and then inspecting that.

```
php /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf > /tmp/sphinx.conf

cat -n /tmp/sphinx.conf | grep 1617 -C10
```

ie sphinx is finding the error in the generated output, not the raw code.